# Building a responsive "centered icons with descriptions" layout

Tags: html, css

Here's a quick mockup of a layout that I'd like to build:

[image: Layout I want to achieve]

How would you do this? I've been playing around with flexbox-based solutions for a bit, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Some additional caveats:

- To make the design responsive, I want to use some Bootstrap-like grid system to split the items over multiple rows on smaller screens. I'm currently using Pure CSS, but I'm open to alternatives including custom media queries.
- Ideally I'd load the icons inside the bubbles from SVG assets. I know I can make four bubble-shaped icons, pop 'em in as `<img>` tags and then horizontally center them with the text, but that's probably not the most elegant solution.
- The four "icon with description" columns should be vertically centered towards one another. Although this is not visible here, it'll affect the layout when the text doesn't line up as neatly as in my mockup.

Comment: This kind of thing can really depend on the rest of the page, but I'd go old school and use display table: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMbzBV. Then you can just change your cell's widths. I'm only hesitant to use flexbox because 1.5 out of 1000 users still use IE 9, which doesn't support flex: https://caniuse.com/usage-table. Or if you're new to CSS you might want to explore bootstrap, which will help you get started. A nice beginning intro: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Unsure why my question was -1'd. If this isn't the right place to ask these types of questions, or there's something I can improve about my question, please let me know in the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this StackBlitz: [FlexBox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xkatq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

In the example I'm using flexbox. If you change the size of the browser window you will see how the icons break down into the next line (responsive).

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
         <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>
     <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>
      <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>
      <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>
      <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.icon-background {
    color: #c0ffc0;
}
```

Comment: How would you apply the circle background to the icon in this example? A wrapping tag with some more alignment tricks to get the icon to center horizontally and vertically? Applying a background to all `fa-icon` tags probably won't do the trick, as the circle is bigger than the image.

Comment: @Pieter you can use stacked icons. Check the updated stackblitz link.

Comment: Thanks for updating! It's good to know that fontawesome has a feature for this. In my specific case, I do prefer Joao's solution since it relies solely on out-of-the-box layouting features though. If I was already using fontawesome, I probably would have gone your way!

Comment: After some experimentation, this turned out to be the best solution after all. I've changed the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. I really enjoy using flexbox, and I think it is not necessary to use bootstrap or other frameworks. Just using flexbox you have a responsive layout with few lines.
2. I used the `<img>` tag, but you can use the CSS tag `background`.
3. Just look at this simple example that I have done. Starting with it you can adapt to your mockup can do whathever it's necessary.

```css
.father {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.element {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.element .element-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fdcb6e;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.element .element-image {
  background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149315.svg');
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.element p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="element-circle"><div class="element-image"></div></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="element-circle"><div class="element-image"></div></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="element-circle"><div class="element-image"></div></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="element-circle"><div class="element-image"></div></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info of flexbox you can find in this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: How would you apply the circular background to the icons in this example? Wrapping the `<img>` tag in another element that adds the background and centers the icon? Replacing the `<img>` tag by `<div>`s having a `background` style attribute that centers the image over a circular background?

Comment: You could have a `<div>` with a class and then load the image with the css propriety `background-image`; I will change my example so you can see it better.

Comment: I changed my answer. There I used two `<div>`. One to do the circle and other to load the image.

Comment: Yes, that's the stuff! Thanks!

Comment: For posterity's sake: I did remove some legacy attributes (I'm not too concerned about old browsers) and apply some responsive design tweaks. My version here: https://jsfiddle.net/peteydiddles/ez0hnw5q/2/